# How to insert a text at the beginning of multiple file?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

i have multiple file like xaa xab xac and i would like to insert the same line in the beginning of all :

here is the command that i found for one :

```
sed -i '1s/^/id,compressedString,url,categorie,date,name\n /' xad
```

and i would like to apply it on my multiple files like x*

Thanks and regards

Comment: Just put all the filenames at the end of the command, and it will do it to each of them.

Comment: Questions about using Unix belong on Unix.SE or SuperUser.com. SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If files are in same directory, try this:

```
sed -i '1s/^/id,compressedString,url,categorie,date,name\n /' x*
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a loop

```
for f in x*; do
   sed -i '1s/^/id,compressedString,url,categorie,date,name\n /' "$f"
done
```